# Android: Recording audio using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio, microphone, recording, mediarecorder

I am trying to do a function in my app that records the sound recording then do some sound analysis after I got the sound recording.

I would like to use MediaRecorder library as I need the sound file and it seems to be a simpler option.

However, I can't seem to be able to start recording based on the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html. 
EDIT: Thanks to @faz15, I can record audio without crashing. However, I cannot stop the recording, thus cannot get the sound clip.
My code is below:

```
package helloworld.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class StartRecording extends Activity {
    final AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/temp"); 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_recording);
        //startRecording();
        try {
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    public void stopRecording(View view) {
        try {
            recorder.stop();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, next_page.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also specify a file name for the output file rather than just a directory path? Also, on most devices you won't have write permissions to "/".

Comment: Do you happened to know where can I get the sound clips that was recorded on the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the appropriate permissions in your Android Manifest?

Comment: Do you mean "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>"?

Comment: Yes they should be the right ones :)

Have a look at [link](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

Comment: Okay! Actually, I also found the resource that you gave me. However, I am not sure how to use it. Do I create a separate class and call it?

Comment: Yes according to that link, it's a helper class and needs to be called like this:

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder(“/audiometer/temp”);
recorder.start();

//….wait a while
recorder.stop();
}
}

Comment: Thanks! It stopped crashing now but I can't stop the recording. i have updated my code on my post.

Comment: Nope. I don't even know if it has recorded any sound file now.

Comment: I found it on the emulator by using Android Perspective. It is working now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case , add the required permissions for it in the

`android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

Maybe your virtual device needs to have audio recording & playback support? Edit your AVD, and add that to the hardware.

Comment: Do you mean "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>"?

Comment: I have added audio playback and audio recording support into my AVD an it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "you cannot stop recording".

However, if it helps anybody, `recorder.release()` should be called after `stop()` and recorder must be set to null if you're done with the object.

Comment: The question was asked in 2012; it's highly unlikely you'll get an exception posted at this late date.